# Chrome Inspect Pixel Ratio doesn't change anything?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In chrome inspect it gives you the option to set/change the resolution and the pixel ratio. I have set a profile for pixel ratio of 1, and set a profile for ratio of 2 and 3 etc. But when i toggle between each profile...nothing changes..

Any idea why?

Even when i changed the setting to Responsive, and toggle between their settings for 1,2,3...nothing happens at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the device pixel ratio emulation feature is independent from the resolution. So you will only see a change if the page you're looking at uses the device pixel ratio, either by using `min-devicepixel-ratio` in CSS or by accessing `window.devicePixelRatio`.

For example, if you [view this demo](https://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/) with iPhone 6 Plus emulation enabled you'll see this:

[image]

Evaluating `window.devicePixelRatio` in the console will return `3`.

Most of the time the device pixel ratio is used to determine whether it's worth downloading a large version of an image at twice the normal resolution.

That means that even when a site does respond to the pixel ratio you won't necessarily see the difference very clearly. But if you check the network panel you'll see that instead of downloading `image.png` `image@2x.png` was downloaded.

Comment: I would guess that most use of the device toolbar is to evaluate web page behavior given a particular viewport that would not normally be usable on your device, which is why DPR is set but the page still renders at a normal size. If you just want to view everything at a 2x zoom, the browser already has a zoom button.